# Rspec doesn't explain failure tests anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, spork

I'm using Rspec with guard and spork for a while, and yesterday I noticed that I didn't had explanations anymore. Now when I type `rspec` (in order to run every tests), I can only see something like `.....................................FDone.` but I don't have the human translation that used to follow. Worse, Rspec doesn't run all the tests since, not even half...

Do you have any idea what could cause such a annoying behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `--format` option

```
rspec example_spec.rb --format documentation
```

The output should look something like

```
something
  does something that passes
  does something that fails (FAILED - 1)
  does something that is pending (PENDING: Not Yet Implemented)
```

More details [documented here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/command-line/format-option#documentation-format).